# How to create sub-lists with 3 elements, but if a sub-list gets a single element then instead create two with 2 elements?

Tags: python

Follows an example to clarify the 2-elements sub-lists use case:

If a list has 10 elements `[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J]` I would like to get 4 sub-lists: `[[A, B, C], [D, E, F], [G, H], [I, J]]`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you determine whether you get `[G, H]` and `[I, J]` instead of `[G, H, I]` and `[J]`? It's very unclear what criteria you use to determine how to splits things. If it's just for a 10-element list and you want to always get the same 2 times 3 and 2 times 2 elements sub-lists I would say this is more than trivial.

Comment: I'm looking for a one liner. I agree with you, this is straightforward to solve by checking if there are single element sub-lists and then dealing with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using an iterator:

```py
L = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"] 
N = len(L)
I = iter(L) 
[[next(I) for _ in range(size)] for size in [3]*(N//3-1) + ([3] if (N%3)==0 else ([2,2] if (N%3)==1 else [3,2]))] 
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F'], ['G', 'H'], ['I', 'J']]
```

Comment: That looks very elegant.

Answer (score 2):

I would do a function:

```
def partition(a):
    arr = np.array(a)
    n = len(arr) # assume that n>=3

    r = n % 3
    if r == 0:
        return list(arr.reshape(-1, 3))
    if r == 1:
        return list(arr[:-4].reshape(-1,3)) + list(arr[-4:].reshape(-1,2))

    # r == 2
    return list(arr[:-2].reshape(-1,3)) + [arr[-2:]]
```

Test:

```
partition(list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))
# [array(['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype='<U1'), array(['D', 'E', 'F'], dtype='<U1'),  
# array(['G', 'H'], dtype='<U1'), array(['I', 'J'], dtype='<U1')]

partition(list('ABCDEFGHI'))
# [array(['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype='<U1'), array(['D', 'E', 'F'], dtype='<U1'),
# array(['G', 'H', 'I'], dtype='<U1')]

partition(list('ABCDEFGH'))
# [array(['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype='<U1'), array(['D', 'E', 'F'], dtype='<U1'),
# array(['G', 'H'], dtype='<U1')]
```

Comment: Hey :)
Your output does not match what the function really returns. Let's say I run `partition(list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))`, I get: `[array(['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype='<U1'), array(['D', 'E', 'F'], dtype='<U1')]`.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
l = list('ABCDEFGHIJ')
n = len(l)
res = [ l[(i if i < n-1 else i-1) : (i+3 if i < n-4 or i == n-3 else i+2)] for i in range(0,n,3)]
print(res)
```

This would give following outputs:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F'], ['G', 'H', 'I']]
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F'], ['G', 'H'], ['I', 'J']]
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F'], ['G', 'H', 'I'], ['J', 'K']]
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F'], ['G', 'H', 'I'], ['J', 'K', 'L']]
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F'], ['G', 'H', 'I'], ['J', 'K'], ['L', 'M']]
```

Comment: That is close, it does not work for `l = list('ABCDEFGHI')` which should give `[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F'], ['G', 'H', 'I']]`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: My future-self will hate it though... xD